# The document “SceneKit Scene.scn” could not be saved

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I'm trying to create a SceneKit scene. I can create it, and edit it, but the moment I try to save it I get the error "The document “SceneKit Scene.scn” could not be saved.".

[image: The document “SceneKit Scene.scn” could not be saved.]

- Affects every `.scn` I try to create, regardless of project (including brand new projects with no changes other than adding this `.scn`), and does so regardless of what changes (if any) I've made to the Scene (even no changes at all gives this message)
- When I locate the file in Finder, *neither* the file *nor* the folder it's in are locked
- Project is on main disk
- Automatic saves also fail with the same error message
- `.scn` file can be opened separately to the project, but again, it cannot be saved
- Neither the default file name nor custom file names help, regardless of whether I change the name in the sidebar after the file is created or at creation time in the New File dialog box
- Deleting the reference and re-adding the file doesn't help
- Making a copy of the file, deleing the original (in Xcode), and re-adding the copy doesn't help
- Cleaning the build folder doesn't help
- Restarting Xcode doesn't help
- Rebooting the mac doesn't help
- Issue **only** affects `.scn` files as far as I can see (*definitely doesn't* affect `.swift`, `.storyboard` or `.metal` files)
- Affects Xcode 10.0, macOS 10.14 (18A391) (Also affected previous version of macOS, but I can no longer remember which version that was)
- Affects Xcode 10.1, macOS 10.14.1 (18B75)
- Affects Xcode 10.2, macOS 10.14.4 (18E226) even worse, as it insists on saving before closing the project, but can't save, so I can only close the project or Xcode by force-quitting.
- Affects Xcode 10.2.1, macOS 10.14.4 (without the bug from 10.2)
- Affects Xcode 11.3.1, macOS 10.14.6
- All my files are in my home directory hierarchy
- Moving project folder to a different subfolder of my home directory (from ~/Documents/ to ~/Desktop/ or to ~/Downloads) has no effect
- All files have the same user/group, both those I can write to and the `.scn` I can't write to
- My user account is in the same group as the files (`ls -l` shows `staff`, as does Preferences.app > Users & Groups > [right click on my account] > Advanced Options… > Group:)
- Exporting the .scn file (File > Export... ) and adding it to the project again doesn't help
- It's only Xcode which has a problem saving this file: if I open it in TextWrangler, I can modify and save it without error. Saving it in TextWrangler *did not* make it saveable in Xcode.
- Resetting user permissions (`` diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u` `` as suggested by @JeremyP)
  didn't help.
- The project is set to use git, and it doesn't help to `commit`, `pull`, or `push`

Why is Xcode failing  to save `.scn`, all the `.scn`, and nothing but the `.scn`?

Comment: I don't think this is a permissions issue. I have exported the scene to a different place and set the group to staff and set the permissions to 777 and still the same issue. I can make changes with a text editor but I can't even save it with Xcode. I raised a bug some time ago on bugreporter.apple.com. I suggest you do the same because they seem to be ignoring it. Hopefully, if more than one person reports the issue, they might take notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug, all you have to do is rename the file in Xcode in the scene editor (on the left hand side where all the files are), mine is "ship.scn" - just rename it to whatever, hit enter. Then you can save. Hit save as. Rename back to original name and save.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It can't save under the new name when renaming the file, likewise for newly created files with non-default filenames.

Comment: @BenRW I save as different name, then save again, it brings up box with "Save as" and u can do "save as" with your original name and it saved for me - recently it stopped happening all together, I think it was related to me having xcode on an external drive, i moved it back to hard drive and no more problem

Comment: @BenRW see my edits, i realized i hadnt fully update my answer cause i figured it out after i wrote my first answer, i wasnt all the way there yet.

Comment: Well, it works, but I'm appalled that I need to do this *every* time I want to save the document, not just the first time. :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Changing permissions did not work. Changing the group did not work. Exporting the scene did not work. In the end I tried the solution suggested here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

Actually, I skipped all the way to step 7 and I haven't done steps 8 and 9 yet, but this fixed the issue for me:

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

Just run the above in a terminal session. Note that I am logged in as an admin user. That might make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with .scn files and Xcode 10. I solved it exporting the .scn file (File > Export... ) and adding it to the project again. Not a great solution but it works.

Comment: I've just tried that, no luck with your method either.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem but I manage to solve it. Now I can save .scn file no matter where project located. Before I solve problem I have to move my project under User's home directory in order to make it work.

kosua20 point out that "**It seems that when creating or importing a .scn file it propagated the user/group and that caused the save to fail**"

I create a project name Test under my another partition. When I open it and try to save it I got this message. You can see Test project is under BOOTCAMP while Macintosh HD has my OS and user home

[image]

[image]

1. Open your Terminal and cd to parent folder which has your project and type "**ls -l**" then Enter to see your folder permission. In my case my Test project folder have group permission of admin, but the account I am using is in group of staff(I will show you later how you can check it). Now I need to change permission to staff instead of admin in order to make .scn file to save successful.

[image]

2. Go to System Preferences -> Users&Groups Unlock it first then right click on user account you are using, it will pop up a menu "Advanced Options..." and click it

[image]

3. In pop up window locate Group and next to it has a name in input field and the name is primary group your account is current in. In my case my account is in staff. So far I can just change staff to admin then .scn file can be save successful but I don't want to.

[image]

4. Back to Terminal while you are in parent directory where it has your project then type "**sudo chgrp -hR [group] [Project folder name]**" then Enter. In my case I have to type "sudo chgrp -hR staff Test" (How command work see here: [chgrp](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchgrp.htm)). In your case it depend on which group your account is current in and project folder name.

[image]

5. After that command if successful type "**ls -l**" then Enter again to check permission of group. If it is group name you are after then you can open your project and modify .scn file and save again to see if it work. In my case .scn is now can be save without any problem.

[image]
[image]

Check your project's group permission and then check if account is in that group, if not then you can either change your account's primary group which I don't recommend or you can use chgrp command to make change to project folder in Terminal. After all this you still have problem then I have no idea.

Hope this help.

Comment: Unfortunately, both the folder (and all files) and my account are already both in the staff group. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with scn files not being able to be saved. In my case the project was saved in another disk and moving it to the main disk resolved it.

Comment: I've just now added "project is on main disk" to my question. Yours is a new solution I've not seen before, it is unfortunate that it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Xcode 10.1. The project was not stored in my home directory hierarchy, and it was assigned to the admin group instead of staff. It seems that when creating or importing a `.scn` file it propagated the user/group and that caused the save to fail. What solved it was to make sure that the `.scn` file and the whole Xcode project were owned by my user and in the staff group.

Comment: Was worth checking, but all my files are in my home directory hierarchy, and all have the same user/group, both those I can write to and the .scn I can't write to. It's only Xcode which has a problem saving this file, if I open it in TextWrangler, I can modify and save it without error. Saving it in TextWrangler did not make it saveable in Xcode. I'm updating my original question with these points too.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue in Xcode 10.2.1. I solved it by changed the location of project or you can create a project in different location.(In my case I synced with iCloud my desktop and documents that may be a problem) now I have created project in different location.

Comment: What do you mean by "the location"? Within the same disk, or to a different disk? I've tried moving the project folder from ~/Documents to ~/Desktop and it didn't help.

Comment: In my case I have changed the location to ~/Downloads it works for me.

Comment: That doesn't help in my case. Thanks for the information though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with playgrounds failing to save, and repeated messages that the file could not be unlocked. I finally solved it by enabling full disk access for Xcode under security and privacy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed my problem by a simple workaround.

You can select your objects in dae file in Xcode editor and hit `command + c` and create a new .scn file in Xcode and paste them using `command + v` there!